react hook form passing props causing forwardRef error
I have really simple form wrapped in functional component. Everything worked even without forwardRef but console kept screaming:
my parent component:
import { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import './App.scss'
import { Stepper } from './stepper/Stepper.component';
import { Grid2 } from '@mui/material'
import { PersonalDetails, UserInfo } from './steps/PersonalDetails.component';
import { ContactDetails, ContactInfo } from './steps/ContactDetails.component';

export class UserDetails {
  personalDetails: UserInfo = new UserInfo;
  contactDetails: ContactInfo = new ContactInfo;
}

function App() {
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);
  const [data, setData] = useState(new UserDetails)
  const ref = useRef(null);
  

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep(activeStep-1)
    console.log(activeStep)
  }

  const handleNext = () => {
    setActiveStep(activeStep+1) 
    console.log(activeStep)   
  }

  const updateFormData = (data: UserDetails) => {
    setData((prevData) => { 
      console.log({...prevData, ...data})
      return ({...prevData, ...data})
  }) }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
      <Grid2 container direction="row"
        spacing={0.5}>
        <Stepper activeStep={activeStep}/>
      </Grid2>
      {activeStep === 0 && (<PersonalDetails updateFormData={updateFormData} handleNext={handleNext} formData={data} ref={ref}/>)}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App

my wrapped component looks like this:
import { Box, Button, Grid2, Input } from "@mui/material"
import { NEXT_BUTTON } from "../configuration/texts"
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import { DatePicker, LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayJS'
import { UserDetails } from "../App";
import { STEPS_INPUTS } from "../configuration/steps";
import { forwardRef } from "react";
import dayjs from "dayjs";

export class UserInfo {
  firstName = "";
  lastName = "";
  dateOfBirth = dayjs(null);
}

export const PersonalDetails = forwardRef((
  props: {
    formData: UserDetails,
    updateFormData: (data: UserDetails) => void,
    handleNext: () => void
  }, ref) => {

  const { formData: { personalDetails } } = props;

  const {
    register,
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isValid },
  } = useForm<UserInfo>({
    mode: 'onChange',
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: personalDetails.firstName,
      lastName: personalDetails.lastName,
      dateOfBirth: personalDetails.dateOfBirth,
    }
  });

  const onSubmit = (data: UserInfo) => {
    props.updateFormData({
      ...props.formData, personalDetails: data
      })
    props.handleNext()
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div ref={ref}>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} style={{ width: '100%' }} >
          <Grid2 sx={{ width: '100%', padding: '5px', borderColor: '#1769aa!important', borderRight: '1px solid', borderLeft: '1px solid', borderBottom: '1px solid' }} container direction="row" columns={12} spacing={0.5} >
            <Grid2 size={2}><Box>First name:</Box></Grid2>
            <Grid2 size={8}><Box><Input type="text" {...register('firstName', { ...STEPS_INPUTS.personalDetails.firstName })} style={{ width: '90%' }}></Input></Box></Grid2>
            <Grid2 size={2}><Box>{errors.firstName && <span className="errorMsg">{errors.firstName.message}</span>}</Box></Grid2>
            <Grid2 size={2}><Box>Last name:</Box></Grid2>
            <Grid2 size={8}><Box><Input type="text" {...register('lastName', { ...STEPS_INPUTS.personalDetails.lastName })} style={{ width: '90%' }}></Input></Box></Grid2>
            <Grid2 size={2}><Box>{errors.lastName && <span className="errorMsg">{errors.lastName.message}</span>}</Box></Grid2>
            <Grid2 size={2}><Box>Date of birth:</Box></Grid2>
            <Grid2 size={8}>
              <Box>
                <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                  <Controller
                    control={control}
                    {...register('dateOfBirth')}
                    render={({ field: {onChange, value} }) =>
                    (<DatePicker
                      value={personalDetails.dateOfBirth.isValid() ? personalDetails.dateOfBirth : value}
                      onChange={onChange} />)}
                    rules={{
                      validate: { required: (value) => STEPS_INPUTS.personalDetails.dateOfBirth.required(value) }
                    }}
                  />
                </LocalizationProvider>
              </Box>
            </Grid2>
            <Grid2 size={2}><Box>{errors.dateOfBirth && <span className="errorMsg">{errors.dateOfBirth.message}</span>}</Box></Grid2>
            <Grid2 sx={{ width: '100%' }} container columns={2}>
              <Grid2 size={1}></Grid2>
              <Grid2 size={1}><Button variant="contained" disabled={!isValid} type="submit" sx={{ minWidth: '100%', marginTop: '20px' }}>{NEXT_BUTTON}</Button></Grid2>
            </Grid2>
          </Grid2>
        </form>
      </div>

    </>
  )
})

I have added forward ref but console still screaming. I think there is type problem in my code using ref inside wrapped component div.

Can anyone please help?
Thanks,
##EDIT
after Yurii's answer


Have you tried typing your useRef with HTMLDivElement like this: const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

yep. console still the same.

import { forwardRef } from "react";

interface Props {}

export const Solution = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, Props>((props, ref) => {
  return <div ref={ref}></div>;
});

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
  <Controller
    name="dateOfBirth"
    control={control}
    render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
     <DatePicker
       value={value}
       onChange={onChange}
     />
    )}
    rules={{
     validate: {
      required: (value) =>
       STEPS_INPUTS.personalDetails.dateOfBirth.required(
        value
       ),
      },
     }}
    />
</LocalizationProvider>


edit error after your solution. VSCode is ok with that. compiler do not.

Which version of React are you currently using? It looks unusual because if your PersonalDetails component is wrapped with forwardRef, you should not be encountering this error. Could you please review the attached screenshots above for further context? PS: I am using  "react": "^18.3.1" and vite

i am using same react. I've published github repo https://github.com/MartinFric/react-hook-form. If you have a time you can double check

@MartinFric An error occurs on line 110 of PersonalDetails. I'm fixing it now.

@MartinFric please take a look at my updated answer

so only problem was that i was using register instead of name in controller?

@MartinFric, the reason is how the DatePicker is handling the ref that it receives from the register function you used previously. I don't know how DatePicker is implemented under the hood, but it looks like it is not wrapped with forwardRef

Thanks, accepted
